# Swiftui Firebase RTDB doesnt update in view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

i'm currently trying to implement a read feature in a messaging app, and so far everything seemed to be going well...

When a user opens up a chat that is unread by him, the value in the database changes, but when he goes back in the navigation view, it still shows that the message is unread. This continues until the app is restarted, then the data seems to be in sync.

The code the update the database:

```
    func markRead(messageKey : String){

    let read = "true"
    let ref = self.ref.child("messages").child(messageKey)
    ref.updateChildValues(["read":read])
    
}
```

The chat is navigated through NavigationView, maybe there's some kind of trick to refresh the view once the back button is hit? I tried using this:

```
self.session.objectWillChange.send()
```

But the user would still need to select a different tab in the bottom navigation and then come back, still, that doesn't update the read status in the app...

Any suggestions or solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't shown any code related to your view. Show the `ObservableObject` and the view that it is stored in -- otherwise, this is impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

does your view contains some tableView to display unread messages?
if yes, then you need to use method `tableView.reloadData()` to update tableView with new information once you back to your navigation view.
I would put this method in `viewDidAppear()`.

I have project where my tableView have to be updated depends on if user logged in/out. It looks similar to your case, user does login in **viewController2** and then return to **viewController1**. So I put `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear()` for **viewController1** and voila result as expected.

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: Do you see the swiftui tag over there?  How do you know that he or she is using UKit?